# How to provide https agent or CA certificates to node's global fetch?

Tags: node.js, fetch-api

Node 18 has global [fetch](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#fetch) http client but because this a browser API it doesn't expose the http agent or tls options.

Node's fetch is implemented by undici, which has a [Agent](https://undici.nodejs.org/#/docs/api/Agent) which can be passed as the dispatcher, but undici is not distributed with node.

```
import { Agent } from 'undici'
fetch(url, { dispatcher: new Agent(agentOptions) })
```

Is there any built in way to set tls options, like ca when using the built-in fetch?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [`agent` option](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch#custom-agent) to pass tls options, e.g.

```
const options = {
  host: '...',
  method: 'POST',
  cert: '...',
  key: '...'
}
const httpsAgent = new https.Agent(options)
const response = await fetch({ agent: httpsAgent })
```

Note that [`https.Agent`](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#class-httpsagent) appears to be underdocumented as stated [here](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/pull/799#issuecomment-633916839) and does not mention the tls options.

I just found out about this today and haven't been able to try it out myself, yet. Will update here as soon as I've verified it.

Comment: Node's built-in fetch is `undici`, not `node-fetch`. `undici` does not respect the `agent` option. 

Undici's dispatcher won't accept a regular https.Agent, but it does accpet undici.Agent. But that isn't exposed globally or via node's built ins, so you have to `npm install undici`.